# Usage of lambdas instead of explicit classes

Tags: java, lambda, comparator

I have programm using explicit classes to sort values:

```
class CompLastNames implements Comparator<String> {
    public int compare(String aStr, String bStr) {
        int i, j;

        i = aStr.lastIndexOf(' ');
        j = bStr.lastIndexOf(' ');
        return aStr.substring(i).compareToIgnoreCase(bStr.substring(j));
    }
}

class CompThenByFirstName implements Comparator<String> {
    public int compare(String aStr, String bStr) {
        int i, j;

        return aStr.compareToIgnoreCase(bStr);
    }
}

public class TreeMapDemo2A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        CompLastNames compLN = new CompLastNames();
        Comparator<String> compLastThenFirst = 
                compLN.thenComparing(new CompThenByFirstName());

        TreeMap<String, Double> tm = 
                new TreeMap<String, Double>(compLastThenFirst);
...
```

[Full code](https://hastebin.com/iqafojuvov.cpp)

And getting the result:

```
Jane Baker: 1378.0
John Doe: 3434.34
Ralph Smith: -19.08
Tom Smith: 123.22
Tod Hull: 99.22

The new account balance of John Doe: 4434.34
```

Then, I'm trying to add lambdas instead of explicit classes like:

```
Comparator<String> compLastThenFirst = 
                ((aStr, bStr) -> aStr.compareToIgnoreCase(bStr));

        TreeMap<String, Double> tm = 
                new TreeMap<String, Double>((aStr, bStr) -> aStr.substring(aStr.lastIndexOf(' ')).compareToIgnoreCase(bStr.substring(bStr.lastIndexOf(' '))));
```

[Full code](https://hastebin.com/cagagajewu.cs)

The result is:

```
Jane Baker: 1378.0
John Doe: 3434.34
Tom Smith: -19.08
Tod Hull: 99.22

The new account balance of John Doe: 4434.34
```

But I didn't get full list *(without Ralph Smith: -19.08)*.
Does anyone know how to write properly? Thanks.

**UPD:**

1)

```
Comparator<String> compLastThenFirst =
            ((Comparator<String>) (a, b) -> a.substring(a.lastIndexOf(' ')).compareToIgnoreCase(b.substring(b.lastIndexOf(' '))))
            .thenComparing((a, b) -> a.compareToIgnoreCase(b));

    TreeMap<String, Double> tm = 
            new TreeMap<String, Double>(compLastThenFirst);
    ...
```

2)

```
Comparator<String> compLN = (aStr, bStr) ->
        aStr.substring(aStr.lastIndexOf(' '))
            .compareToIgnoreCase(bStr.substring(bStr.lastIndexOf(' ')));
Comparator<String> compLastThenFirst = 
        compLN.thenComparing((aStr, bStr) -> aStr.compareToIgnoreCase(bStr));


        TreeMap<String, Double> tm = 
                new TreeMap<String, Double>(compLastThenFirst);
    ...
```

Comment: Why does `CompThenByFirstName` not split then compare? It seems to just sort by the whole lot, this will cause unexpected behaviour.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to call `thenComparing`.

Comment: And what @Sweeper said - ignoring the ugliness of the code, it's just wrong.

Comment: Yes, @Sweeper, I also suppose that I need method `thenComparing`, but how to add it correctly?

Comment: @BoristheSpider it's example Shildt book

Comment: It can't be - there's strange declaration of variables, declaration of unused variables. I suspect you've made changes...

Comment: @BoristheSpider check [listing 16](https://github.com/hloong/Java-The-Complete-Reference-Ninth-Edition-SourceCode/blob/master/Java%20The%20Complete%20Reference%20Ninth%20Edition%20SourceCode/Chap18.lst)

Comment: Wow. Throw the book away and find a better one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need to reimplement what [`thenComparing(Comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#thenComparing-java.util.Comparator-) does:

```
(aStr, bStr) -> {
    int compareResult =
        aStr.substring(aStr.lastIndexOf(' '))
            .compareToIgnoreCase(
                bStr.substring(bStr.lastIndexOf(' '))
            )
    if (compareResult != 0)
        compareResult = aStr.compareToIgnoreCase(bStr);
    return compareResult;
}
```

(Also [see the OpenJDK source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/be44bff34df4/src/share/classes/java/util/Comparator.java#l188).)

Or you could use `thenComparing` by assigning to an interim variable (like in the first example):

```
Comparator<String> compLN = (aStr, bStr) ->
        aStr.substring(aStr.lastIndexOf(' '))
            .compareToIgnoreCase(bStr.substring(bStr.lastIndexOf(' ')));
Comparator<String> compLastThenFirst = 
        compLN.thenComparing((aStr, bStr) -> aStr.compareToIgnoreCase(bStr));
```

However, the simplest way to write a comparator like that is probably like this, using [`comparing(Function,Comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-java.util.Comparator-):

```
Comparator.comparing(str -> str.substring(str.lastIndexOf(' ')),
                     String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)
          .thenComparing(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)
```

(Also see the [`String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER) doc.)

Comment: Thanks, Radiodef for the detail answer!

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @Sweeper in the comments you forgot the call to `Comparator#thenComparing`. The corresponding code with lambda expressions would be:

```java
Comparator<String> compLastThenFirst =
        ((Comparator<String>) (a, b) -> a.substring(a.lastIndexOf(' ')).compareToIgnoreCase(b.substring(b.lastIndexOf(' '))))
        .thenComparing((a, b) -> a.compareToIgnoreCase(b));
```